# How to set tab li active and show after page is load

Tags: jquery, .net, tabs

i want to set last tab to active after page load in asp.net and i try to get id in "li" and set it in localstrage already but is not show last tab. How Can i do in this case.Please help. Thank you so much.

i try to set tab in jquery like this

```
 function SETactive() {

        var activeID = $("#myTab li.active").attr('id').toString();
        localStorage.setItem('lastTab', activeID);
        var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
        if (lastTab) {
            $("#opd_tab").removeClass('active');
            $("#"+lastTab).addClass('active');
            $("#"+lastTab).tab('show');
        }
    }
```

In activeID ,I get a last tab allready

```
 <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
     <li class="active" id="opd_tab"><a href="#opdForm" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Medical Certificate OPD Form</a></li>
     <li id="ipd_tap"><a href="#ipdForm" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Medical Certificate IPD Form</a></li>                                   
 </ul>
```

Comment: No offense, but this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I want set last tab is active after page is load.

Answer (score 0):

According to the bootstrap reference page : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs you can you active a tab with

```
<script>  
$(function () {
   $('#myTab a:last').tab('show')
})
</script>
```

so you can easily try this in your case

```
$('#ipd_tap a').tab('show')
```

you need to work with `a` tag not `li`, and do not try to add or remove `active` class by yourself, let the plugin do the job for you

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:-

```
// get the actual pathname:
var path = location.pathname;
// filter menu items to find one that has anchor tag with matching href:
$('#myTab li').filter(function(){
    return '/' + $('a', this).attr('href') === path;
// add class active to the item:
}).addClass('active');
```

Hope it will help you :)